# Expandable listview collapses other groups when clicking empty group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I got a problem. I used to this code to collapse all groups except selected group in expandable listview android:

```
mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                    mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        });
```

but some groups are empty, so I want clicks on empty groups will not close other groups.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter = (ExpandableListViewAdapter)mExpandableListView.getAdapter();
            if (adapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition) > 0) {
                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                    mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
                }
                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        }
    });
```

Pls change the adapter type to match yours. Hope that helps!